# Explain 0-extension algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, label, approximation

I'm trying to implement the 0-extension algorithm.

It is used to colour a graph with a number of colours where some nodes already have a colour assigned and where every edge has a distance.  The algorithm calculates an assignment of colours so that neighbouring nodes with the same colour have as much distance between them as possible.

I found this paper explaining the algorithm: http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1FBA2D22588CABDAA8ECF73B41BD3D72?doi=10.1.1.100.8049&rep=rep1&type=pdf
but I don't see how I need to implement it.

I already asked this question on the "theoretical computer science" site, but halfway the discussion we went beyond the site's scope:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/explain-0-extension-algorithm

Can anyone explain this algorithm in layman's terms?
I'm planning to make the final code opensource in the jgrapht package.

Answer (score 0):

The objective of 0-extension is to *minimize* the total weighted cost of edges with different color endpoints rather than to maximize it, so 0-extension is really a clustering problem rather than a coloring problem. I'm generally skeptical that using a clustering algorithm to color would have good results. If you want something with a theoretical guarantee, you could look into approximations to the MAXCUT problem (really a generalization if there are more than two colors), but I suspect that a local-search algorithm would work better in practice.

Comment: i tought the MAXCUT algorithm could not handle precolored nodes, or does that just need a more general version of the algorithm?  my current implementation in brute fore (optimized with branche skoping) calculates 35 nodes with 3 colors in 12min, i need at leased 64 nodes under 10min

Comment: For two colors, you just need to enforce the constraint that the vectors corresponding to the precolored nodes have dot product -1. In general, with k colors, you want -1/(k-1), but the rounding gets trickier. I would try ceil(lg k) random hyperplanes that separate the precolored nodes.